# client has 2X1910 switches 1x1920 switch traffic not passing correctly some nodes are responding to pings and others are not

Tags: routing, vlan, network

New to vlans, bridging across multiple L3 switches and not sure where to start so here goes in hopes of learning
Layout is this

```
1910-24g-POE (Switch01)>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
-internet-vlan2 (no interface ip)Port 17-24 router on port 17 address is 199.199.199.254/24
-Wifi-Vlan3 199.199.105.64\26 (Ports 12-16)
-MGMT-Vlan4 199.199.150.1\26(ip for vlan interface) port 6
-security-Vlan5 199.199.175.250\24(ip for vlan interface)
-Corp-Vlan6 199.199.180.64\26(Ip for vlan interface)
-Trunk 
1-2   > Switch02 >1910-16G (tagged vlans 1,2,3,4,5,6)
3-4 Switch04 > upstairs (tagged vlans 1,2,4,5)(removed and direct to port 18 to resolve ping issues)
5-6 Spare(tagged vlans 1,2,3,4,5,6)

1910-16g(Switch02)>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
-internet-vlan2 (no interface ip)passed 
-Wifi-Vlan3 199.199.105.63\26 (Ports 12-16)
-MGMT-Vlan4 199.199.150.2\26(ip for vlan interface)port 6
-security-Vlan5 199.199.175.251\24(ip for vlan interface)
-Corp-Vlan6  199.199.180.63\26(Ip for vlan interface)
-Trunk 
1-2   > Switch 01 >1910-16G Tagged vlans (1,2,3,4,5,6)
3-4 Switch 03 > Rack Tagged vlans (1,3,4,5,6)
5-6 Spare
Synology on port 15-16 untagged vlan5(unpingable)

1920-48G-POE(Switch03)>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
internet-vlan2 (no interface ip)Port 17-24 router on port 17 address is 199.199.199.254/24
Wifi-Vlan3 199.199.105.62\26 (Ports 12-16)
MGMT-Vlan4 199.199.150.3\26(ip for vlan interface) port 6
security-Vlan5 199.199.175.252\24(ip for vlan interface)
Corp-Vlan6 199.199.180.62\26(Ip for vlan interface)
Trunk 
1-2   > Siwtch 02 >1910-16G
ISCSI-VLAN7 - Local isolated traffic only
VMotion Vlan8 -Local isolated traffic only
Synology on port 40 (unpingable from any L3 switch or computer on port 18of switch1)
```

So I built this network and was able to get everything connected to vlan02 tv , PVR, synology
Problem is the synology  is sending email reports to the email server, which I see on my phone and is relaying by gmail,  but when trying to connect directly I can’t even login or use the finder app to configure doesn’t work,  but when I connect the diskstation to the router I can Login and problem is I want the disk station on switch 02 but cant see it , and when i go to diag tools i can/t ping the computer i'm using from any of the 3 switches, nor can i ping the sinology from any of the 3 switches, where do I go from here?

yes that is correct there is 2-1910's and 1-1920

was doing some more work this morning . so i have the home vlan5 i have a computer connected to help try an troubleshoot this from my pc on sw01-p18 /vlan5 to the second computer on SW02-P9/vlan5 i can ping successfully i can access it no issues, the synology is on SW02-P15/16(trunked)
-pinging to the inet gateway from computers Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
-ping from gateway to computer.10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
-All ports that are access are untagged to the perspective Vlan it will be hosting.
-Checked mac address tables on both my PC and the 3 switches for the devices that are not responding and the mac are listed in all 4 tables.

may requre some instruction ?
Check whether routing is enabled on the gateway(s). (is this the IPv4 routing table your talking about?) Check whether every gateway has a route to each remote (not sure what your asking? address pointing to each sw from each switch?)(=not directly connected subnet). On the 19xx you're likely restricted to setting static routes. on the i have the following routes setup for each of the following switches
firewall is 199.199.175.254/24
Sw01

1. List item

| Dest | Mask | Pref | Next hop | Interface |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | 10 | 199.199.175.254\24 | Vlan5 |
| 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | 30 | 199.199.175.251\24 | VLAN5 |
| 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | 30 | 199.199.175.250\24 | VLAN5 |
| 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | 31 | 199.199.175.252\24 | Vlan5 |
| 199.199.175.0 | 255.255.255.0 | 10 | 199.199.175.254\24 | Vlan5 |

Sw02
|Dest                     | Mask                    |Pref                 |Next hop                      |Interface|
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------|-----------------------------|------------|
|0.0.0.0                |0.0.0.0                   |60                    |199.199.175.254\24   |Vlan5      |
|199.199.175.0   |255.255.255.0     |10                    |199.199.175.250\24   |VLAN5    |
|0.0.0.0                 |0.0.0.0                  |9                      |199.199.175.254\24   |Vlan5      |

Sw03
|Dest                     | Mask                    |Pref                 |Next hop                      |Interface|
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------|-----------------------------|------------|
|199.199.175.0   |255.255.255.0     |15                    |199.199.175.251\24   |VLAN5    |
|199.199.175.0   |255.255.255.0     |10                    |199.199.175.254\24   |Vlan5      |

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask about that on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Those are *HPE* 1910/1920s, correct?

First, you need to make sure that each end node is properly connect to its home VLAN.

For that, either ping the default gateway from the node or vice versa. You should also be able to ping from any other node in the same VLAN and IP subnet. Of course, the local firewall needs to permit pinging (ICMP echo request and response).

Alternatively, you can check the MAC address table on the uplink switch for the end node's MAC. If it isn't there (or in another VLAN) the access port is not configured correctly. Access ports need to use a single, untagged VLAN.

If the MAC in the VLAN look like their all on the directly connected switch and none on the inter-switch (trunk) links, then the trunk isn't set correctly. On a trunk you need to make sure that you either tag all VLANs or tag all but one. The untagged VLAN must match on either trunk end.

If your layer-2 structure works correctly, check if your set up (default) routes on the end nodes correctly. Check whether routing is enabled on the gateway(s). Check whether every gateway has a route to each remote (=not directly connected subnet). On the 19xx you're likely restricted to setting static routes.